# Python 2.6: encode() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python

Hopefully simple question here, I have a value that based on if its unicode, must be encoded. I use the built in string.encode class

code is simple:

```
if value_t is unicode:
                values += (value.encode('utf-8', errors='backslashreplace'), None)
                continue
```

However it returns "encode() takes no keyword arguments"

I am running this in python 2.6, I couldn't find any documentation saying this didn't exist in 2.6
Is there a way for me to make sure it isn't being overwritten by an encode function in a different library? or some sort of solution to it.

It seems like you are able to use string.encode in 2.6 (https://docs.python.org/2.6/howto/unicode.html) so I am not really sure why it wouldn't be working. I am working on one file in a fairly big system, so I am worried this is somehow being overwritten. Either that or some module I need isn't installed..But i am lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python docs for [encode](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) explain why you're seeing this issue. Specifically: `Changed in version 2.7: Support for keyword arguments added`

Answer (score 2):

Since method signatures tend to change from version to version, You should always read the relevant documentation to version you are working with

From [str.encode](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) documentation for python 2.6, the method signature is:

```
str.encode([encoding[, errors]])
```

There is no `errors` keyword argument, but the second parameter can be used for the same purpose.